# Query - Sort this query by a column which returns Distinct rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
"id",
                  "fn" || ' ' || "ln" || '/' ||  "bi" || '('|| TRUNC((months_between(sysdate, "bi") /12)) || ')/' || "pol" || '/ ' || "pol2" AS "INFO",
    "cn" ,
    "ci",
    TO_CHAR("di" , 'DD-MON-YYYY')  AS "DIST",
    "cif" AS  "Cand. Indp." AS "CIF FLAG",
    TO_CHAR("ecd", 'DD-MON-YYYY')   AS "ECD DATE",
     trim(both '/' from ("DSD") ) AS  "DSD DATE",
    trim(both '/' from ("TSD"   ))  AS "TSD DATE",
    "com"  AS "COMMENTS",
    "SMF" AS "SM Flag"
FROM "MY_TABLE"
ORDER BY "ln";
```

I get the error ORA-01791: Not a selected expression.

I googled the error and the problem seems to be the distinct  and order by don't work together. I tried to group by instead of distinct and use max("ln"), but with the concatenated columns I have not been able to figure out how to group them. I am looking essentially how to sort the results on ln?

Comment: `distinct` and `order by` do work together. You just need to include the columns to order by in the select list. What is the primary key of `MY_TABLE`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is no primary key. This is also a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not select by ORDER BY "ln"

you can only select by selected column then or add in select

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "id",
     "fn" || ' ' || "ln" || '/' ||  "bi" || '('|| TRUNC((months_between(sysdate, "bi") /12)) || ')/' || "pol" || '/ ' || "pol2" AS "INFO",
     "ln",
    "cn" ,
    "ci",
    TO_CHAR("di" , 'DD-MON-YYYY')  AS "DIST",
    "cif" AS  "Cand. Indp." AS "CIF FLAG",
    TO_CHAR("ecd", 'DD-MON-YYYY')   AS "ECD DATE",
     trim(both '/' from ("DSD") ) AS  "DSD DATE",
    trim(both '/' from ("TSD"   ))  AS "TSD DATE",
    "com"  AS "COMMENTS",
    "SMF" AS "SM Flag"
FROM "MY_TABLE"
ORDER BY "ln";
```

or change order by

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "id",
     "fn" || ' ' || "ln" || '/' ||  "bi" || '('|| TRUNC((months_between(sysdate, "bi") /12)) || ')/' || "pol" || '/ ' || "pol2" AS "INFO",
    "cn" ,
    "ci",
    TO_CHAR("di" , 'DD-MON-YYYY')  AS "DIST",
    "cif" AS  "Cand. Indp." AS "CIF FLAG",
    TO_CHAR("ecd", 'DD-MON-YYYY')   AS "ECD DATE",
     trim(both '/' from ("DSD") ) AS  "DSD DATE",
    trim(both '/' from ("TSD"   ))  AS "TSD DATE",
    "com"  AS "COMMENTS",
    "SMF" AS "SM Flag"
FROM "MY_TABLE"
ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize it had to be its own separate column in the select statement. It works!